# I want override animate effect on html & body

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, window-scroll

Suppose below is my code. i am not responsible to make change directly to code. hence i am doing it via console. and i want to unbind this html & body animation but someotherFunction() should work as it is. there may be too many functions as well beyond my imagination like below and i want all to work as it is but only animate should be unbind.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
    }, 2000);
   someOtherFunction();
   someMoreFunctionIDontKnowAbout();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Answer

We will unbind the `.click` event then we will add the new binding.

```js
$('#button').unbind("click");
$('#button').click(function() {
   someOtherFunction();
   someMoreFunctionIDontKnowAbout();
});
```

---

### Side Note

I recommend if this is something you will be doing a lot and only want for yourself that you should install `tampermonkey` or a similar tool to run jquery/javascript of your own on a specific domain.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick reply. but i want to mention one thing that i am using this code through some kind AB tesing tool.

Comment: @DesignerAshish okay? can you explain what you are trying to add as a requirement?  like no jquery?